# Google App Script to Qualtrics API: download, unzip, and push CSV to Sheet

Tags: api, csv, google-apps-script, qualtrics

I like to use Google Apps Script to automatically once a day:

1) fire off an API request to Qualtrics that returns a ZIP file

2) unpack the ZIP file

3) read the emerging CSV file into a Google Sheet

I'm a relative novice in coding and integrating it all to make it work but can understand concepts and basic syntax, and edit scripts with some guidance. Many thanks for your help! Some more notes:

**STEP 1)** the Qualtrics API necessitates to

first create the file via [Create Response Export](https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/csv)

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://uwa.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "x-api-token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "surveyid": "SV_1F9ldubC3O1BcUJ",
    "content-": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\r\n    \"format\": \"csv\",\r\n    \"surveyId\": \"SV_1F9ldubC3O1BcUJ\",\r\n    \"includedQuestionIds\": [],\r\n    \"useLabels\": true\r\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

then take the returned file-ID (e.g. "ES_e7s2ja08o9o4df6cd7ptckmfma") to download the file via [Get Response Export File](https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/get-response-export-file)

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://uwa.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/ES_e7s2ja08o9o4df6cd7ptckmfma/file",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "x-api-token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**STEP 2)** unzip the downloaded file via [unzip (blob)][3]?

**STEP 3)** offers probably two options:

(a) to instruct a Google Sheet to download the data into itself via =importData("URL") which requires the CSV to be saved somewhere like my Google Drive

(b) to push it into the Google Sheet via its the [Google Sheet API][4]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the appropriate docs to get started.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

If you get stuck share what you have tried and what errors you are getting.